# Lookup using multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet filled with data below (and in the image):

[image]

Now there's this other sheet where the user will only be inputting the column "Gender" and "Age" values and the excel formula should be fetching the associated factor. Please help me with one such formula.

For e.g. If the user puts Male and 23, the formula should return 3. say Male was entered in Cell D46 and 23 was entered in E46 of Sheet named "Sheet4" and the table shown above happens to be in "Sheet1"

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, now I can visualize what you meant in your other comments in your previous question, it's a rather easy redo of our other formula.

[image]

Formula in `F3`:

```
=INDEX(C1:C13,MATCH(1,(ROW(C1:C13)>=MATCH(F1,A1:A13,0))*(B1:B13=F2),0))
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Notice that these formulas will return a wrong result if, lets say you extend till females age of 29, and you will search for male, it will still return the value for female. It will however not fail when your searchcriteria would be always right.

You could prevent this in this case (because you only really have one criteria and a fixed range with this formula in `F3`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(F1="Male",INDEX(C2:C9,MATCH(F2,B2:B9,0)),INDEX(C10:C13,MATCH(F2,B10:B13,0))),"No result")
```

Just enter normally. What it does is it checks what gender type is chosen and choses it's lookup index accordingly.

Another option would be to use `SUMPRODUCT()` like so :

```
=IF(F1="Male",SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9=F2)*(C2:C9)),SUMPRODUCT((B10:B13=F2)*(C10:C13)))
```

Also, if you are curious what formulas do and want to learn from them, a great way to do so is using the build-in formula evaluate function, that will show you step by step what the formula will calculate.

EDIT

Tried, as per your comment, to break it down for you so you understand what is going on:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I have got multiple such tables with different combinations of data. Will it be possible for you to help me out in another such table. Sample data is at - https://imgur.com/a/OTchLKS .I am not raising another question to this since all these questions revolve around similar issues with only different data columns structure.

Comment: could you please assist me on the above?

Comment: @user8107531, I answered your question, I can't keep changing answers cause your data changes. The essence the way the formula works stays the same. Look carefully at the answer I gave in your previous question. You basically have to add to that in the same fashion. I'll help you out if you can't get it working.

Comment: I tried using  =INDEX(F1:F13,MATCH(1,(ROW(E1:E13)>=MATCH(1,(A1:A13=R3)*(B1:B13=R4)*(C1:C13=R5)*(D1:D13=R6),0))*(E1:E13=R7),0)) But it didn't work out for me and throws an #N/A error

Comment: @user8107531, see edited answer. You can put all these formulas in one formula but that's useless if you not first understand what they do.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for being so patient with me. Breaking down the formula actually helped me understand what was going on. Thanks again. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I've learned a good trick how to fill in the blank cells:

1. Select all cells in the column with the "gender" values.
2. Goto Special, Blanks. (You active cell should be `A3`)
3. In the formula bar, type `=A2`. (I believe that `A2` contains the word "Male")
4. Press Ctrl+ENTER (don't forget the Control key for filling all selected cells)

As a result, `A3` will be copied from `A2` and contain the word "Male", `A4` will be copied from `A3` and will now also contain the word "Male", ...
Further: this stops at the first occurence of the word "Female" (this cell is not selected), and for the later cells, the copying happens in the same way as before.

From here, it should be far easier to achieve your goal.